# Issue with python project structure and different pip versions

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip

I'm facing some issues with an existing working project structure after a `pip` upgrade from version `23.0.1` -> `23.1`.
I'm using python `3.9.7` and a virtual environment.

My project structure:

```
Project/
|-- config.py
|-- jobs/
|   |-- one.py
```

`one.py` content:

```
import config
```

When I run `jobs/one.py` after installing my project using the upgraded pip `one.py` throws the following exception:

```
Exception has occurred: ModuleNotFoundError
No module named 'config'
  File "Project\jobs\one.py", line 1, in <module>
    import config
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'config'
```

This structure worked well till the upgrade, so ideally I would like to keep the existing structure with no changes to the imports, so it can still work with the older version of `pip`.

Comment: You might need to use relative imports, this means `from .. import config` because imagine if another module uses the config file name like you, this would be a mess :)